# How many ordered pairs (a,b) satisfy a^2=b^3+1, where a and b are integers?

Tags: number-theory

(A)2
(B)3
(C)4
(D)5

I got 2 pairs (0,-1), and (3,2), but the correct answer is 5.

Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Migrate to math.